# Programmatically change Mac volume

Tags: cocoa, macos, volume

Is it possible to change the volume of a Mac using code?

Comment: [XKCD](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/im_an_idiot.png) is undecided on the question (the strip ends before he gets around to it)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Sound (or other) System Preferences in Mac OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170294/change-sound-or-other-system-preferences-in-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 1):

If you are coding in C++ you can use the Carbon API http://developer.apple.com/carbon/
Could you be more specific about your problem?

Comment: I need to change the current output volume, like you do with the speaker icon in the menu bar or the volume buttons on the keyboard.